# How to implement Admob ads with firebase [as google introduced in 18 May]

Tags: android, admob

I want to implement admob ads with firebase ads (as google introduced in 18 May) for Android to my applications. i have no idea i also visit [**this site**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/) but not cached idea how to do.

> Is there any guide on how to do this or any sample/ example?
>
> Why we link app two times to Admob and Firebase?
>
> Why Main reasons using this, Is any advantages?

If someone know about this please share with us thanks a lot . if you try down rating please give reason in comments.

Comment: The site you link to has guides for setting up AdMob with Firebase. Look for "Get Started" under the AdMob iOS and Android sections in the left-hand nav. The guides also link directly to GitHub repos with sample code.

Comment: I created a tutorial about integrating AdMob with Firebase http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2016/06/21/android-admob-firebase/. But I created a new project for this. I didn't linked existing apps. But the code and most of the steps should be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should download [Android Studio 2.2 preview](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/android-studio-2-2-preview-1). There is inbuilt functionality to implement this.

From Tools select Firebase

[image]

select AdMob from list given

[image]

and there you will get all things by clicking on **Set-up AdMob**

[image]